# Go Mysql connection refused due to a burst of connections

Tags: mysql, go

Go version 1.18. MySQL server is version 8. System is 2018 MacBook Pro i9 6-cores, 32GB RAM.

However, mysql connection is refused during mysql.QueryRow(). error message is:

`panic: dial unix /tmp/mysql.sock: connect: connection refused`

**PLEASE NOTE: I already find root cause(see my comment in the following code) and have a solution(using semaphore).**

**I MUST use socket instead of localhost when setting db connection.**

The root cause is 2000 Go routines try to send query to MySQL simultaneously. How to solve this problem? My solution is to use semaphore to limit the number of concurrent go-routines, for example 100. I have tested, semaphore solution works well. I actually do not want to use semaphore to limit the number of concurrent mysql queries.

**Question: why I can not have 2000 go-routines sending query at the same time.**

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    mysqlDriver "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

type SomeStruct struct {
  a string
  b string
}

func main() {
    cfg := mysqlDriver.Config{
        User:   "DB_USER",
        Passwd: "DB_USER",
        Net:    "unix",
        Addr:   "/tmp/mysql.sock", // MySQL is installed on local
        DBName: "databaseName",
    }

    mysql, err := sql.Open("mysql", cfg.FormatDSN())
    if err != nil { 
        panic(err) // tested, panic is not caused here.
    }

    mysql.SetMaxOpenConns(5000)
    mysql.SetMaxIdleConns(5000)

    if err = mysql.Ping(); err != nil {
        panic(err) // tested, panic is not caused here.
    }

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for i := 0; i < 2000; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            var someStructVar SomeStruct   
            err := mysql.QueryRow("select a, b from table where id = ?", i).Scan(&someStructVar.a,  &someStructVar.b) 
            if err != nil {
                panic(err) // this is where the panic happens. 
            }
        }
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

my.cnf is:

```
[mysqld]
max_connections=5000
connect_timeout=300
```

Comment: In your code all `panic`s are BEFORE you start goroutines and try to run queries: you have not even connected to a db yet.

Comment: Is that your actual code? Are you actually invoking `Scan()` with no arguments? And is `Scan()` with no arguments actually returning the `dial unix /tmp/mysql.sock: connect: connection refused` error? Is this example code supposed to be a [mcve]?

Comment: @mkopriva updated code with more details.

Comment: Change `Net:    "unix"` to `Net:    "localhost"` ?

Comment: DB Connection works very well if I use semaphore to limit the number of concurrent go-routines. So, root cause has nothing to do with db connection config.

Answer (score 0):

If your panic error occur before code

```
mysql.SetMaxOpenConns(5000)
```

Then the error is when connecting to the database, try changing the connection configuration to the database

Comment: @PerfectCompanionMe when you have problems with `database/sql` the use of "sample code" can be misleading. This is because **underneath** many components of that package require the explicit release of resources (see all of the `Close()` methods that are declared by various types of that package). If you do not release those resources then the connection pool (`sql.DB`) will not be able to re-use existing connections and instead will try to establish new ones until it hits the sever limit. So unless you provide a [mcve] it will NOT be possible to *exactly* point out what you are doing wrong.

Comment: updated code with more details.